# How to import multiple files from multiple folders using readRDS

Tags: r, import

I want to import a large number of files from two folders. The files are in RDS format. The datasets are standardized and I want to select the variables to be imported during import.

That is my codes:

```
path_to_cases<-"1_GROUPE BARIA/..../..../CLEAN DATASETS"
path_to_controls<-"2_GROUPE CONTROLE/..../..../CLEAN DATASETS"

folder_paths <- c("path_to_cases", "path_to_controls")

variable_to_select <- "myvar"

data_list <- map(folder_paths, function(folder_path) {
  file_paths <- list.files(folder_path, pattern = "SEJOUR_BARIA.*\\.RDS$", full.names = TRUE)
  
  map(file_paths, ~ readRDS(.) %>%
        select(all_of(variable_to_select)))
})
```

However I have an empty list after importing. What is wrong with my codes? SOS please.

Comment: `c("path_to_cases", "path_to_controls")` is a vector of two strings, this has nothing to do with the same-named _objects_. Remove the quotes here and try again.

Comment: Still empty despite removing the quotes

Comment: When you run `list.files(folder_paths[1], pattern=".*\\.RDS$", full.names=TRUE)` manually, do you see files? I can only guess that this might be either (a) case-sensitivity (`.rds$` perhaps), or (b) working-directory problems.

Comment: You were right it was a path problem. I provided wrong paths. But now I have a problem with the function select. I got this error message: Error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `select()`:
! `select()` doesn't handle lists.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: That suggests that at least one of your `.rds` files contains a `list` and not a frame-like object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
folder_paths <- c("path_to_cases", "path_to_controls")
    
    
    for (folder_path in folder_paths) {
        rds_files <- list.files(folder_path, pattern = "\\.rds$|\\.RDS$", full.names = TRUE)
      
      for (rds_file in rds_files) {
        data <- readRDS(rds_file)
        file_name <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(rds_file))
    
        variable_to_select <- c("myvar")
        selected_data <- data[, variable_to_select, drop = FALSE]
    
        assign(file_name, selected_data)
        rm(data, selected_data)
      }
    }
```